# DolphinDB python API: Use DolphinDB type 'timestamp' in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dolphindb

I create a streamtable in DolphinDB and one column type is defined in type 'TIMESTAMP', while time can only be defined in type datetime64[ns] in pandas DataFrame which will be cast to nanotimestamp in DolphinDB. If the dataframe is directly inserted into the streamTable, the time may be wrongly processed. Is there any other way to deal with this problem apart from using SQL statement to cast the type of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

The method `append` of the object `tableAppender` in Python API appends the local DataFrame to an in-memory table or partitioned table. In the process, DolphinDB will automatically convert the temporal type.

The statement of `tableAppender` is used as follows:

```py
tableAppender(dbPath="", tableName="", ddbSession=None, action="fitColumnType")

dbPath: path of the distributed database. Fill "" if it is an in-memory table.

tableName: name of the table

ddbSession: session handle that has connected to the DolphinDB server.

action: assigned action when appending the table. Currently only "fitColumnType" action is supported, indicating the conversion of time column type.
```